# Convert Dictionary<int, string> to strongly typed class ICollection Using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-6.0

I working on .NET CORE 6 application. I have `Dictionary<int, string>` that I need to convert to an ICollection of class object. I have create separate profile class; refer below. However I am getting error.

```
Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
List`1 -> ICollection`1

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, 
System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, 
Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]], 
System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]
```

`Entity Class`

```
 public class AIMSchema
{
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string MachineCode { get; set; }
}
```

`AutoMapper profile`

```
public class AIMConfigProfile : Profile
{
    public AIMConfigProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Dictionary<int, string>, AIMSchema>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TransactionDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.ContainsKey(1)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.MachineCode, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.ContainsKey(2)))
            ;
    }
}
```

Calling from class to covert dictionary data...

```
var ff = _ambientState.Mapper.Map<ICollection<AIMConfigProfile>>(filteredStructuredData);
```

Comment: `source.ContainsKey(1)` returns `bool`, but `TransactionDate` is `DateTime`. You probably want to get the value with key `1` and convert that into a `DateTime`.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample data of dictionary and the expected result

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you have a dictionary with specific entries containing the machine code and transaction date(and by your example you know the keys which correspond to these).
Here's one way to do it.

```
IMapper mapper = new MapperConfiguration(opts =>
{
    opts.CreateMap<Dictionary<int, string>, AIMSchema>()
        .ForMember(x => x.TransactionDate, op => op.PreCondition(x => x.ContainsKey(1)))
        .ForMember(x => x.TransactionDate, op => op.MapFrom(x => DateTime.Parse(x[1])))
        .ForMember(x => x.MachineCode, op => op.PreCondition(x => x.ContainsKey(2)))
        .ForMember(x => x.MachineCode, op => op.MapFrom(x => x[2]));
}).CreateMapper();

List<Dictionary<int, string>> data = new()
{
    new()
    {
        {1, "2022-01-01" },
        {2, "code foo" }
    },
    new()
    {
        {1, "2022-02-01" },
        {2, "code bar" }
    },
};

ICollection <AIMSchema> result = mapper.Map<List<Dictionary<int, string>>, List<AIMSchema>>(data);

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.MachineCode);
    Console.WriteLine(item.TransactionDate);
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
}
```

And this is my output:
[image: result evidence]

Comment: Use `PreCondition()` instead of `Condition()` otherwise AutoMapper will resolve the source value, that is access the dictionary and that can lead to `KeyNotFoundException`. Read more about conditional mapping in the [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html#preconditions).